# How to read a TEXT column and treat is as byte array

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, visual-foxpro

We have an ancient foxpro application with a function which has to be converted to C#.

Basically, all it does is to read a XLS file from a SQL Server database table and save it on the local disc. This file serves as an Excel worksheet template.

The binary XLS file information is stored in a `TEXT` column (which makes me nervous) and is extracted via FoxPro with this single line:

```
lnResult = SQLEXEC(THISFORM.Hconn, "select XExcell from MyTable", "xy")
SELECT xy
IF !EMPTY(xy.xExcell) AND !ISNULL(xy.xExcell)
  COPY  memo xy.xExcell to (SomeFile)
```

The problem is that C# (or at least the ADO command) treat the column as a string. Well, that is what the reader comes up with when I execute a

```
MyADOCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Edit: Which is an implicit string and cannot be casted to a byte array.

So, here's my problem: The data is in some binary form in the SQL Server and has to be pulled and treated as a raw byte array (and finally written to disc, giving it an extension of `.XLS` and pray that Excel is able to read the file).

Any idea how to achieve this? The following code obviously does not work

```
var s=(string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
var enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
var template= enc.GetBytes(s);
var fs = new FileStream(excelTemplateFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
bw.Write(template);
bw.Flush();
bw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

I also tried to cast the `TEXT` column as an `IMAGE`, but that does not work either (SQL Server complains that it cannot convert). I know the problem is the fact that a text (a string of characters) is not a stream of bytes, but if FoxPro can do it, C# should be able as well, no?

Edit: The contents is approx 3MB big.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you can't just use `var s=(byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();`? Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yes, I have. Sorry, I did not mention it. This causes a runtime error as the string returned by the query cannot be converted to a byte array.

Comment: > The binary XLS file information is stored in a TEXT column

Shudder ...

Comment: Yes. I could not believe it. But, that's legacy code, so what can I do? Except of improving it as soon as the old crap is turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the SQL query to cast the column to varbinary as follows:

```
select cast(cast(XExcell as varchar(max)) as varbinary(max)) from MyTable
```

Then:

```
var bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("your file name", FileMode.Create))) 
{
   writer.Write(bytes);
}
```

**EDIT:** Double casting TEXT -> varchar(max) -> varbinary(max), because direct casting from TEXT -> varbinary(max) is not allowed

Comment: The cast looks promising. I will check that tomorrow. Thanks for the hint, as well as the snipped demonstrating a nice and compact way of moving the stuff to a file.

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote. a `TEXT` is not castable to a `varbinary(max)`

Comment: Try to double cast: `cast(cast(XExcell as varchar(max)) as varbinary(max))`

Comment: Sorry, I have to upvote and mark your answer as 99% correct :-)
Please edit your solution to cast to `varchar(max)` first and then to `varbinary(max)`:
`cast(cast(xExcell as varchar(max)) as varbinary(max))`

Comment: Did not see your post, sorry. I figured it out myself.